# Make textbox in UserControl become readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a couple of textbox in the UserControl. How am I going to change them into readOnly = true/false depending on the conditions?

In my content page, I have the following codes:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="item" Src="~/User_Controls/itemDetails.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent_1" runat="server">
<uc1:item id="ItemList" runat="server"></uc1:item><br />
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (//Some Conditions)
        {
            //turn ItemList.txtItemName = enable read Only
        }

        if (//Some other Conditions)
        {
            //turn ItemList.txtItemPrice = disable read Only
        }
}
```

In the ItemDetails.ascx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }        

    public string itemName
    {
        get { return txtItemName.Text; }
        set { txtItemName.Text = value; }
    }

    public string itemPrice
    {
        get { return txtItemPrice.Text; }
        set { txtItemPrice.Text = value; }
    }

    //and get...set... for other controls
```

Comment: What properties are defined on `ItemDetails.ascx`? Also, your ASPX markup is incorrect, as you open with `<uc1:item>` and close with `</uc1:Addr>`.

Comment: set Enabled False for disable and true for enable

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz in the ascx.cs, it is just a bunch of get...set... (View edited question above)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad what do you mean? Please be more specific

Comment: ``txtBox.Enabled=false`` or ``true``

Comment: Did you try TextBox box = (TextBox)this.ItemList.FindControl("txtItemName");box.ReadOnly = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create property in User control `ItemDetails.ascx`. and assign the property to the textbox enable property.

**User control**

```
public bool EnabledtxtItemName { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtItemName.Enabled = EnabledtxtItemName;
}
```

Now you can access the property from respective page you have added the user control.

**Web page**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ItemList.EnabledtxtItemName = false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is working now. I confused myself with the true/false. Thank you